# Sage: Catch MACSYMA-QUIT is Undefined

Tags: sage, maxima, computer-algebra-systems, ecl

### My Situation

When I'm using the `sage.all` module just on the normal `python` shell, `sage.all` throws an **error** on running **methods like `solve` or `assume`**:

```
>>> import sage.all as sg;a=sg.var('a');sg.assume(a==0);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/assumptions.py", line 412, in assume
    x.assume()
  File "expression.pyx", line 1397, in sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.assume (sage/symbolic/expression.cpp:8428)
  File "lazy_import.pyx", line 212, in sage.misc.lazy_import.LazyImport.__getattr__ (sage/misc/lazy_import.c:1865)
  File "lazy_import.pyx", line 148, in sage.misc.lazy_import.LazyImport._get_object (sage/misc/lazy_import.c:1268)
  File "/opt/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/maxima_lib.py", line 153, in <module>
    ecl_eval("#$%s$"%l)
  File "ecl.pyx", line 1236, in sage.libs.ecl.ecl_eval (sage/libs/ecl.c:7040)
  File "ecl.pyx", line 1251, in sage.libs.ecl.ecl_eval (sage/libs/ecl.c:6977)
  File "ecl.pyx", line 257, in sage.libs.ecl.ecl_safe_eval (sage/libs/ecl.c:2839)
RuntimeError: ECL says: THROW: The catch MACSYMA-QUIT is undefined.
```

Running `assume` or `solve` on the `sage` shell (and preprocessor) works like it is supposed to do.

### My Question

What can I do to get `sage.all` to work correctly on `python`?

Thanks - if anything's unclear concerning my question, please comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use the Sage copy of the IPython shell.

```
$ sage -ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 16 2013, 21:48:36) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import sage.all as sg

In [2]: a = sg.var('a')

In [3]: sg.assume(a==0)

In [4]:
```

Comment: To amplify: Sage is more than just a Python library — it requires various other components be present and located in specific places. So using `sage --python` (or `sage --ipython`) will use a version of Python which has access to all of the relevant components.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Is it just impossible to run Python scripts using `sage.all` on a normal Python interpreter? Or are there special things I can do to get `sage.all` running?

(I don't need/want Sage's Python preprocessor, I just write normal Python scripts accessing the `sage.all` module)

Comment: `sage --python` runs a normal Python interpreter, with no preprocessor. Try it: evaluate `2^3`, for example. But Sage's library will run commands like `maxima` and `cython` and `Singular`, and it will also try to access various libraries. It is not just a self-contained Python library.